# Viewed Item Not In Catalog

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

I am trying to activate the behavior trigger for Abandoned Cart and want the PI data extension to be filled.

I import the product catalog daily from the FTP server. In the email recommendation status I see a lot of errors for items that are not in the product catalog. But every product is in the psv-file. That I checked.

I use the complete catalog with master and variants (SkuID). The errors appear in item, shopping cart and conversion. We use ProductCode for articles in the collect code. The mapping is ok.

Any idea what the next step to solve this problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this help article: [Einstein Recommendations 'An item not in the catalog was viewed' in the status console, but item exists in the catalog](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312443&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

> Ensure the ITEM Parameter is a string:
>
> The item parameter must be a string value and can not be an INT value  for example
>
> "item":"12345"  vs "item": 12345

Otherwise, you would need to provide your payload and the productcode/skuid combo you see in Email/Web Recommendations >> Reporting >> Admin tools and search for the item in question

Comment: Ok. Thanks. We did come a big step forward. Only one item left which is not part of the catalog for reasons. Question: Does the status report needs to be error-free that the PI and Behavioral Trigger Data Extensions are getting populated?

Comment: No, it simply won't fire for that product, or be added to any DE